# Can JSON strings be converted to fractions for equations when building REST API in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating an API for a picture framing calculator.  I am using Node JS with Express.  The code that I'm using is this:

```js
        app.post("/api/calculator/singlematapi", (req,res) => {
        
        let FrameWidth = req.body.FrameWidth;
        let FrameWidthFraction = req.body.FrameWidthFraction
        let FrameHeight = req.body.FrameHeight;
        let FrameHeightFraction = req.body.FrameHeightFraction;
        let PictureWidth = req.body.PictureWidth;
        let PictureWidthFraction = req.body.PictureWidthFraction;
        let PictureHeight = req.body.PictureHeight;
        let PictureHeightFraction = req.body.PictureHeightFraction;
        let MatOverlap = req.body.MatOverlap;
        let MatOverlapFraction = req.body.MatOverlapFraction
        let width = (1/2)*((FrameHeight+FrameHeightFraction)-(PictureHeight+PictureHeightFraction)+(MatOverlap+MatOverlapFraction));
        let height = (1/2)*((FrameWidth+FrameWidthFraction)-(PictureWidth+PictureWidthFraction)+(MatOverlap+MatOverlapFraction));
        res.send(`Width Cut = ${new Fraction(width).toString()}", Height Cut = ${new Fraction(height).toString()}"`);
    });
```

Therefore, a JSON POST request would be:

```json
{
    "FrameWidth": 16,
    "FrameWidthFraction": 0,
    "FrameHeight": 20,
    "FrameHeightFraction": 0,
    "PictureWidth": 11,
    "PictureWidthFraction": 0,
    "PictureHeight": 17,
    "PictureHeightFraction": 0,
    "MatOverlap": 0.5
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that instead of a decimal - a fraction such as `1/2` can be inputted instead.  For example:

```json
{
    "FrameWidth": 16,
    "FrameWidthFraction": 0,
    "FrameHeight": 20,
    "FrameHeightFraction": 0,
    "PictureWidth": 11,
    "PictureWidthFraction": 0,
    "PictureHeight": 17,
    "PictureHeightFraction": 0,
    "MatOverlap": 1/2
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that although I am able to convert the `output` from decimal to fraction using a library and this piece of code:

```js
res.send(`Width Cut = ${new Fraction(width).toString()}", Height Cut = ${new Fraction(height).toString()}"`);
```

...I am not able to use a `fraction` as an `input` instead of a decimal.

Unless I'm misunderstanding - it states here:  [JSON data types](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm) - that `Fractions` pertaining to `Numbers` can only be displayed in decimal type formatting such as `0.5` like I have above under `MatOverlap`.

However, according to the same page it states that a `forward slash` can be used in a `string`.

Can I use the `forward slash` as the `solidus` to indicate a fraction when JSON data is inputted?

When I attempted to use a `string` by changing the above to:

```json
{
   "MatOverlap": "1/2"
}
```

...then it throws `NaN` error.

---

*****EDIT***** **8/1/2022**

This is for further clarification regarding one of the solutions to this question:  [this solution found below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73185496/can-json-strings-be-converted-to-fractions-for-equations-when-building-rest-api/73185592?noredirect=1#comment129260789_73185592) by **some random nerd**.

Particularly this comment:

> You can enter just a 0 with this method as well

I wrote a piece of code to serve as an example of what I mean:

```js
app.post("/add", (req, res)=>{
    let n1 = req.body.n1;
    let n2 = req.body.n2.split("/").reduce((a, b) => a / b);
    let sum = n1 + n2;
    res.send(`Sum = ${sum}`);
    
});
```

If I input:

```json
{
   "n1": 1,
   "n2": "0/1"
}
```

The response is:  `Sum = 1`

```json
{
   "n1": 1,
   "n2": "0"
}
```

The response is: `Sum = 10`

See how `0` needs to be written as `0/1` in order for the math to work correctly?  When the input is `0` I'm looking to write just a `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert the fraction input to decimal.

```js
let MatOverlap = req.body.MatOverlap.split("/").reduce((a, b) => a / b)
```

To also accept mixed fractions:

```js
let MatOverlap =
  req.body.MatOverlap.split("/").reduce(
    (a, denom) =>
      a.split(" ").reduce((int, numer) => +numer + int * denom) / denom
  );
```

Comment: This works very well!  Do you know of a way that if the input is `0`, then I can enter just a `0`?  This solution requires that I enter `0/1`.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You can enter just a `0` with this method as well

Comment: It's still not working for me - I still have to write `0/1` instead of just `0`.  I edited my above post with a further explanation of what I mean.  Thank you again.

Comment: oh yeah, then I'll edit it so it makes sure the result is a Number.

Comment: Hi again.  Is there a way to restructure this line of code to accept mixed number inputs like `2 1/4`?  It works great for just whole numbers and just fractions.

Comment: This is the complete solution!!  Thank you for everything, seriously!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert string expression to number using `eval`. Yes yes. But first sanitize it because it's a dangerous command to run on input.

```js
var req = {
  body: {
    MatOverlap: "1/2"
  }
}

let expr = req.body.MatOverlap;  
expr = expr.replace(/[^0-9//]/g, "");

let MatOverlap = eval(expr);
console.log(MatOverlap * 6)
```